# Does pressure vary in a steady stream of water flowing down from a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

A steady stream of water falls down a pipe. Assume the flow is incompressible. How does the pressure vary with height in the following stream?

The answer to this problem as stated by my book was that the pressure is same at all points in the stream. I can understand that the pressure would be atmospheric and not vary with height since the liquid is accelerating freely downwards. However, the velocity of water stream is increasing as it falls down, so applying the Bernoulli's theorum there should be variation of pressure. So why is this not the case here?

Comment: if your pipe has the same radius, how can the velocity in the completely file pipe vary with the hight?

Comment: Is it not accelerating though? Or do we assume that in "steady state" there is a continuous flow of water, hence it is not accelerating?

Comment: @trula Also if I replace the pipe system with a tap, would pressure differ in that case?

Comment: I think you are forgetting about the potential head term (hdg) in while applying Bernoulli's equation as the two points will not be at the same height

Comment: @HarshalChaware3791 That really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no pump at the top of the pipe and no flow restriction (no valve e.g.) at the bottom then the pressure at the top and bottom is identical (atmospheric pressure) and Bernoulli's equation reduces to:

$$\frac12 \rho v_1^2+\rho gh_1=\frac12 \rho v_2^2+\rho gh_2$$

There's no pressure gradient at all.

Assume (for argument's sake) that: $v_1 \approx 0$, then:

$$v_2\approx\sqrt{2 g\Delta h}$$

which is of course the classic formula for free falling objects.

Comment: I understood what I did wrong, Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: How do you know the pressure is not different inside the pipe?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny   Since as the pressure in the end-points is equal it would have to be a 'parabolic' type of profile? What would cause that? I can't see it...

Comment: @Gert, I dont think it will happen, but I do not think it is that obvious from the math.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I agree it's not proven here, I just don't really see how to prove it. At the end of the day, the flow is a 'fall' of fluid packets that don't interact (inviscid flow assumption) with each other...

Comment: @Gert, I agree, I dont know either. But if the velocities are different, then the flow Q=av will be different, which is inconsistent with an incompressible fluid.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I've come across a similar question several times and often thought the flow would probably break up, due to the acceleration. See e.g. how flow out of a faucet reduces in cross-section.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but in such a case using Bernoulli's equation is wrong. The velocity you obtained is likely meaningless

Comment: I don't see why the velocity would be meaningless: the 'packets' still free fall.

Comment: the flow will start with a velocity of zero, and the velocity you calculated is the velocity of an element of fluid that started at height h. You cannot apply the equations blindly when the conditions do not apply. -1.

Comment: Sorry. I  disagree. Never mind.